# pegar dados de variavel na input

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Fala Povo!
Tenho um sistema que cadastrada produtos e cria o que preciso no campo de dados, porem to em uma parte crucial, depois que crio os campos que preciso ele gera input com esses campos! o problema é:

Quando envio via post o input ta como abaixo

```
<input type="text" name="campo[]" class="campo_input" placeholder="<?php echo $campo; ?>" />
```

preciso enviar o valor desse campo e separar pra inserir no bd, pois esta num while!!!

```
<?php
include "conecta.php";
   mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$lista =$_POST['lista'];

$sku = implode(",", array_map(function ($item) {
 return sprintf('"%s"', $item);
}, $_POST['campo']));


$sqli = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $lista VALUES ('', '".$sku."')")  or die(mysql_error());

if($sqli){
    echo $sku;
}
else {
    echo 'deu erro';
}

?>
```

ele pega legal, porem nao consigo separar pra incluir no banco, ele da a resposta

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

justamente porque ele pega a resposta e nao separa, joga tudo em uma unica coluna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
>
> =
>
> A contagem de colunas não corresponde à contagem de valores na linha 1

Verifique se o numero de `colunas` na query corresponde ao numero de valores passados no `value`

> **Tudo vai depender do valor da  variável `$lista`**

A query também tem erro `'".$sku."'` o correto é simplesmente `$sku` conforme soluções abaixo

1. Supondo que o HTML é composto de 4 inputs conforme exemplo abaixo

   `<input type="text" name="campo[]" class.....`
2. Assumindo que a variável `$lista` é composta com o nome da tabela seguida pelos nomes das colunas entre parêntesis

   ```
   $lista = "nomeTabela(nomeColuna,nomeColuna1,nomeColuna2,nomeColuna3,nomeColuna4)";
   ```
3. Sua query deve ser

   ```
   $sqli = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $lista VALUES ('', $sku)")  or die(mysql_error());
   ```
4. Caso o nome da tabela não esteja na variável `$lista`

   ```
   $sqli = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO nomeTabela $lista VALUES ('', $sku)")  or die(mysql_error());
   ```
5. Caso a primeira coluna seja `AUTO_INCREMENT`

   ```
   $lista = "nomeTabela(nomeColuna1,nomeColuna2,nomeColuna3,nomeColuna4)";

   $sqli = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $lista VALUES ($sku)")  or die(mysql_error());
   ```
6. Existe a possibilidade de estar passando somente o nome da tabela através da variável

   ```
   $lista = "nomeTabela"; 

   $sqli = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO $lista VALUES ($sku)")  or die(mysql_error());
   ```

Comment: perfeito! obrigado!